# Dropdown lists - two options

Tags: html, html-select

i have two dropdownlists:
user can choose values and when he cliked on button it redirect him on the wwww...

```
function loadNew()            {          
selectLetter = document.forms[0].letter.value.toString() + document.forms[0].number.value.toString();               
switch (selectLetter)                {                    
case  "12":             
location.href = "http://";                        
break;                  
case "21":                      
location.href = "http://";
break;                  

default:                      
location.href = "http://";                        
break;                }   
 }                                
 </script>    
 </head>
```

Body:

```
 <body onLoad="visibilityT()">        <form onSubmit>        <select name="letter" id="letter" ">
 <option></option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>

 </select><select name="number" id="number">
 <option></option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>

 </select>             
 <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="loadNew()">        
 </form>
```

How to disable option that user can choose the same values?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a two step process, initially show only the first list, then based on the selection from that list you can dynamically create a new list(or add option, if second list is also created at the start, but empty) in the javascript.

Comment: Here are some links that can help, though they only give approach to do it....http://neerajkhandelwal.wordpress.com/2011/10/22/creating-html-elements-dynamically/

Comment: and http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamic-combobox-listbox-drop-down-using-javascript/